# How to prevent insertion of value if value exists in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique

Given 3 columns in a table `tblEmails`,

- `email1`, nvarchar(50), NULLs not permitted
- `email2`, nvarchar(50), NULLs permitted
- `email3`, nvarchar(50), NULLs permitted

how do I prevent insertions or updates of a (non-NULL) value to *any* of the three columns if the value already exists in *any* of the other columns?

I was hoping to apply a `CONSTRAINT` by checking if the `UNION ALL` of the three tables contains the value to be inserted, but it seems count() can't be used in `CONSTRAINT`s.

- Any solution implementable via the SSMS gui would be ideal.
- I looked through at least a dozen SO posts, some SE posts, and articles online, but could not find a solution (or one that I could understand).

Comment: Why does your table have a `tbl` prefix?

Comment: ...and why is your table denormalized? What if someone has more than 3 email addresses?

Comment: You say "any of the three tables" - but you've only described 1 table. Did you mean to say "any of the three columns?" instead?

Comment: What tool is "SSMA"? Do you mean "SSMS" instead?

Comment: I *assume* they mean SQL Server Migration Assistant, @Dai , but no sure how that helps here.

Comment: @Dai Legacy database. That's how I found it. We don't store more than 3 emails for a user. Only primary is required hence NULL not permitted for email1 column. Yes, SSMS (corrected).

Comment: @kaanchan I, personally have at least 50 different email addresses (check my Office 365 account if you don't believe me) - but your system cannot accommodate me. So you should fix that.

Comment: @Larnu It's a recognized SO tag and tool I'm more familiar with than writing direct contraint, index, and trigger queries. I've seen solutions on SO where SSMS steps were provided and that was really helpful.

Comment: SSMS and SSMA are completely different tools, @kaanchan .

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. It was a typo. I had tagged SSMS correctly, but seeing your comment I edited to correct SSMA to SSMS.

Comment: @Dai I appreciate your comments. The question is unaffected and remains the same.

Comment: [wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF) already explain really clear and also contain great example, I would not say normalization is ALWAYS NEEDED but if you will query, manipulate those data frequently then you should always try to proper normalize your tables.

Comment: @kaanchan for this case you will want to create another table `email` that contain email data and a FK that ref the `user` then no matter how many email a user might have, you can simply keep adding more row with that FK point to that user, also it will be easy to check if a user have duplicate email.also setting constraint on FK and email then you can prevent any duplicate insert (which is the most safest way IMO)

Comment: @T.Peter Thanks for the reference and clarification. I get it now. I guess there is more to consider if we're intentionally limiting number of emails we store per usr, and further if we are assigning them primary, secondary, and tertiary preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function which is then called by the check constraint. Following an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_chkMail(@mail nvarchar(100)) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mails WHERE mail1 = @mail) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mails WHERE mail2 = @mail) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mails WHERE mail3 = @mail)
END
```

and then

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mails  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_mails] 
CHECK  ((dbo.fn_chkMail([mail1]))+(dbo.fn_chkMail([mail2]))+(dbo.fn_chkMail([mail3]))=1)
```

See fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6f375/7/1

Comment: You got me started, but the offered code seems to fail for normal cases: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6f375/17

Comment: When I tried to enter in SSMS, the check always failed. By switching the + to AND and the "= 1" to "< 2" I was able to get it to work. I think this is because the CONSTRAINT checker is doing a row by row check and NULL values return 0 rather than 1.

Comment: Try this instead: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a96ab/2

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent modifying values using `update` when values are already in the table.  Unfortunately, that suggests a trigger.

I think the logic looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tblEmails_update ON tblEmails
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM inserted i JOIN
                     deleted d
                     ON i.<primary key> = d.<primary key>
                WHERE (d.email1 IS NOT NULL OR
                       d.email2 IS NOT NULL OR
                       d.email3 IS NOT NULL
                      ) AND
                      (COALESCE(d.email1, '') <> COALESCE(i.email1, '') OR
                       COALESCE(d.email2, '') <> COALESCE(i.email2, '') OR
                       COALESCE(d.email3, '') <> COALESCE(i.email3, '') 
                      )
               )
       )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('You can not update emails when value is already present', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;   
END;
```

I would suggest though that there might be a simpler data model.  For instance, I would recommend storing the emails in a separate table with one row per email.  You would use this table as:

- When you insert a value into one email, you insert all three.
- You have a unique index on the entity id and email number.
- You don't allow updates on the table.

EDIT:

I suspect that you really want a `unique` constraint.  You are not looking *within* a row but across *all* rows.

If that is the case, you simply have the wrong data model.  You need a table with one email per row.  This might require a column to identify *which* email, but something like this:

```
create table entity_emails (
    entity_email_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    which_email int,
    email varchar(255)
);
```

Then you want the following constraints:

```
check (which_email in (1, 2, 3));
unique (entity_id, which_email);
unique (email);
```

The first two limits the number of emails to 3 per entity.  The third insists that the `email` be unique over all rows and entities.

With the right data model, what you need to do may not require a trigger.

Comment: I was unable to make this work. My SQL knowledge is limited, but I think I plugged in the right values. Every update to the table triggered a failure. Looking at the code, I don't understand where a comparison to the whole and original columns is happening; only to the updated and deleted rows.

Comment: @kaanchan . . . You shouldn't be writing triggers until you are comfortable with SQL.  I suspect someone else should be doing this.

Comment: I generally agree. I have programming and QA background and doing checks along the way. In some cases I think learning by trying is okay. 

Are you checking against the whole table at any point (not just the inserted and deleted tables)? How else will you you know if an email exists in another (untouched, pre-existing) row?